# Is the trunc function very slow?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2013, truncation

**tl;dr:** `double b=a-(size_t)(a)` faster than `double b=a-trunc(a)`

I am implementing a rotation function for an image and I noticed that the `trunc` function seems to be awfully slow.

Looping code for the image, the actual affectation of the pixels is commented out for the performance test so I don't even access the pixels.

```
double sina(sin(angle)), cosa(cos(angle));
int h = (int) (_in->h*cosa + _in->w*sina);
int w = (int) (_in->w*cosa + _in->h*sina);
int offsetx = (int)(_in->h*sina);

SDL_Surface* out = SDL_CreateARGBSurface(w, h); //wrapper over SDL_CreateRGBSurface

SDL_FillRect(out, NULL, 0x0);//transparent black
for (int y = 0; y < _in->h; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < _in->w; x++){
            //calculate the new position
            const double destY = y*cosa + x*sina;
            const double destX = x*cosa - y*sina + offsetx;
```

So here is the code using `trunc`

```
size_t tDestX = (size_t) trunc(destX);
size_t tDestY = (size_t) trunc(destY);
double left = destX - trunc(destX);
double top = destY - trunc(destY);
```

And here is the faster equivalent

```
size_t tDestX = (size_t)(destX);
size_t tDestY = (size_t)(destY);
double left = destX - tDestX;
double top = destY - tDestY;
```

The answers suggest not to use `trunc` when converting back to integral so I also tried that case:

```
size_t tDestX = (size_t) (destX);
size_t tDestY = (size_t) (destY);
double left = destX - trunc(destX);
double top = destY - trunc(destY);
```

The fast version seems to take an average of 30ms to go through the full image (2048x1200) while the slow version using `trunc` takes about 135ms for the same image. The version with only two calls to `trunc` is still much slower than the one without (about 100ms).

As far as I understand C++ rules, both expressions should return always the same thing. Am I missing something here? `dextX` and `destY` are declared `const` so only one call should be made to the `trunc` function and even then it wouldn't explain the over three times slower factor by itself.

I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2013 with optimizations (/O2). Is there any reason to use the `trunc` function at all? Even for getting the fractional part using an integer seems to be faster.

Comment: `const` in C++ is not the same thing as `constexpr`. Can you please post more code?

Comment: Well I can't have them `constexpr` because the destination changes in the loop. They're only constant during the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On modern x86 CPUs, int <-> float conversions are quite fast - typically inline SSE code is generated for the conversion and the cost is of the order of a few instruction cycles.<sup>1</sup>

For `trunc` however a function call is required, and the function call overhead alone is almost certainly greater than than the cost of an inline float -> int conversion. Furthermore, the `trunc` function itself may be relatively costly - it has to be fully IEEE-754 compliant, so the full range of floating point values has to be dealt with correctly, as do edge cases such as NaN, INF, denorms, values which are out of range, etc. So overall I would expect the cost of `trunc` to be of the order of tens of instruction cycles, i.e. an order of magnitude or so greater than the cost of an inline float -> int conversion.

---

1. Note that float <-> int conversions are not always inexpensive - other CPU families, and even older x86 CPUs, may not have ISA support for such conversions, in which case a library function will normally be used, and the cost of this would be similar to that of `trunc`. Modern x86 CPUs are a special case in this regard.

Comment: I checked the disassembly and this is what happens indeed. As far as you know, would some different compilers or using options to disable strict compliance to IEEE-754 change the result an replace the function by the faster equivalent?

Comment: With gcc and related compilers there is `-ffast-math` which relaxes some of the strict IEEE-745 constraints - I have no idea whether this allows for e.g. an inline `trunc` though. I would guess not, as `trunc` tends not to be widely used as an explicit function call IME - typically most people would just use float->int truncation.

Comment: Thank you I think I got a better understanding of all this now. It's not something one would notice usually (only a few more cycles) unless the call is inside a loop.

Comment: Indeed - it would normally be insignificant, but this kind of thing sometimes shows up when you profile your code and notice that some relatively trivial function is appearing somewhere in the top 10 most expensive functions! Thankfully it's easy enough to optimise, as you have observed.

Answer (score 4):

The way you're using it, there's no reason for you to use the [`trunc` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/trunc/) at all. It transforms a double into a double, which you then cast into an integral and throw away. The fact that the alternative is faster, is not that surprising.

Comment: What about the second case? Any explanation why it's faster to promote the integer into a double when I want to get the fractional part?

Comment: Just to clarify your comment: you're comparing it to ``double left = destX - tDestX;``?

Comment: Yes. I want to understand why it's slower to get the fractional part with `trunc` rather than casting to integer then promoting it.

Comment: It's very hard to tell if this is even what's happening - you'd need an intimate knowledge of the system (which you didn't specify). Are the instructions generated by subtracting a double from a double the same from subtracting an integral form a double? Does the ALU do exactly the same thing? The promotion here is *conceptual* not necessarily *physical*.

Comment: Well I did say Visual Studio 2013 so I didn't think I had to precise I was using a Windows architecture. I tried with both x86 and x64 with similar results so I didn't consider this to be relevant. The CPU is a Intel i7-4650.

Comment: Oh, so you did - sorry. Notwithstanding, the point is that the promotion is conceptual.

Comment: Well I do not have extensive knowledge on the floating-point unit in x86 CPUs but what I found here http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_121.html suggests that there is an actual promotion going on. "FISUB instructions convert an integer source operand to double extended-precision floating-point format before performing the subtraction."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79384/discussion-between-ami-tavory-and-meneldal).